# How to prevent dynamically created table from overflowing its div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gridsplitter

Here is a picture of what is happening.  I want vertical and horizontal scroll bars and the table to fill its container div and not overflow.

[image]

The dividers shown are from a jquery library called gridsplit.

```
<script src="dist/jquery.gridsplit.optimised.js"></script>
```

The table header is hard-coded but the body is created dynamically.

Here is the html from one attempt:

```
 <div style="float:left; overflow:auto; width:100%; height:95%">
            <div id="grid4" class="grid">
                <div class="innerGrid">
                    <div id="leftCol" class="gridColumn" gs-width="15%">
                        <div class="gridCell" gs-height="60%">
                            <div class="fillCell">
                                <div id="parent">
                                    <select id="selectWatchlist" style="float:left"><option value="My Portfolio">My Portfolio</option></select>
                                    <button id="addSymbol" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> 
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Syms
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div style="display:table-cell">
                                    <table id="watchlist" style="width:100%; border:0; cellpadding:0; cellspacing:0; margin-bottom:5px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Sym</th><th>Price</th><th>% Change</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>     
                                </div>                       
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gridCell" gs-height="40%">
                            <div class="fillCell"><a>Notes</a></div>
                        </div>
```

I've been googling all day and have tried dozens of combinations to no avail.  Suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to tell without being able to run your code. Look for the `<>` button in the question editor to create an interactive snippet. There we can see what you're seeing. Be sure to include all dependencies as well.

Comment: The code is complex.  It would take days to try to simulate just the piece that shows the problem.  I am hoping someone has seen something similar where a table overflows its parent div despite having a height percent and overload:auto set in that div.

Comment: Is there another way we can see it in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to simply add `display:block` like this:

```
.gridCell .fillCell {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Now it has the scrollbars and doesn't overflow.  Here is a picture:

[image]

I could swear I tried that, but apparently not.